# Why am I getting empty input value on expose filter $form_state variables for taxonomy?

Tags: views, panels

I have created a panel. Inside the panel there is one content pane and one view expose filter present.

Normal exposed filter works properly but [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) does not works as expected: I am getting empty value after submit.

I have checked using `views_exposed_form_alter` hook.

```
$form_state['view']->exposed_input['shs_term_node_tid_depth']
```

Is there any alternative way to set or get the expose filter input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply little trick and my issue solved.
Used default taxonomy search and hide it.

```
(function($) {

Drupal.behaviors.tushar_1 = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('#edit-shs-term-node-tid-depth').change(function(){
      var eid = $('#edit-shs-term-node-tid-depth').val();
      $('#edit-tid ').val(eid);
    });
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

Solved my issue.